# Expansion of Beagleboard?

Tags: beagleboard

I have been wondering about Beagleboard and it's possibilities of supporting many embedded OSes

What I was wondering was:

- Using a SSD as a SD Card? Does it depend on the OS?
- Relocation of the Usb ports?

Comment: "Using an SSD as an SD Card" does not make sense to me.  Can you please explain?

Comment: I mean, using a SSD (or Flash memory) as a primary storage for data.

Answer (score 4):

You can run a lot of different OS on the Beagleboard, but set it up to do Multiboot is probably a little bit tricky.

I think the easiest is to have a couple of different SD cards and switch the card when you need another OS on the board.